# Large INNODB Tables Locking Up

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a database table that is giving me those headaches, errors when inserting lots of data.  Let me break down what exactly happens and I'm hoping someone will have some insight into how I can get this figured out.

Basically I have a table that has 11+ million records in it and it's growing everyday.  We track how times a user is viewing a video and their progress in that video.  You can see below what the structure is like.  Our setup is a master db with two slaves attached to it.  Nightly we run a cron script to compile some statistical data out of this table and compile them into a couple other tables we use just for reporting.  These cron scripts only do SELECT statements on the slave and will do the insert into our statistical tables on the master (so it'll propagate down).  Like clockwork every time we run this script it will lock up our production table.  I thought moving the SELECT to a slave would fix this issue and since we aren't even writing into the main table with the cron but rather other tables, I'm now perplexed what could possibly cause this locking up.

It's almost as if it seems that every time a large read on the main table (master or slave) it locks up the master.  As soon as the cron is complete, the table goes back to normal performance.

My question is several levels about INNODB.  I've had thoughts that it might be indexing that would cause this issue but maybe it's other variables on INNODB settings that I'm not fully understanding.  As you would imagine, I want to keep the master from getting this lockup.  I don't really care if the slave is pegged out during this script run as long as it won't effect my master db.  Is this something that can happen with Slave/Master relationships in MYSQL?

The tables that are getting the compiled information to are stats_daily, stats_grouped for reference.

The biggest issue I have here, to restate a little, is that I don't understand what can cause the locking like this.  Taking the reads off the master and just doing inserts into another table doesn't seem like it should do anything on the master original table.  I can watch the errors start streaming in, however, 3 minutes after the script starts and it will end immediately when the script stops.

The table I'm working with is below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Position` smallint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Progress` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ViewCount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DateFirstView` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', // Use unixtimestamps
  `DateLastView` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', // Use unixtimestamps
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `VID` (`VID`,`UID`),
  KEY `UID` (`UID`),
  KEY `DateLastView` (`DateLastView`),
  KEY `ViewCount` (`ViewCount`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15004624 ;
```

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas on this?

**UPDATE:**
The errors I get from the master DB

```
MysqlError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'invalid query UPDATE stats SET VID = '13156', UID = '73859', Position = '0', Progress = '0.8', ViewCount = '1', DateFirstView = '1375789950', DateLastView = '1375790530' WHERE ID = 14752456
```

The update query fails because of the locking.  The query is actually valid.  I'll get 100s of these and afterwards I can randomly copy/paste these queries and they will work.

**UPDATE 2**
Queries and Explains from Cron Script

**Query Ran on the Slave (leaving php variables in curly brackets for reference):**

```
SELECT 
    VID, 
    COUNT(ID) as ViewCount,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(DateLastView), '%Y-%m-%d') AS YearMonthDay,
    {$today} as DateModified
FROM stats
WHERE DateLastView >= {$start_date} AND DateLastView <= {$end_date}
GROUP BY YearMonthDay, VID
```

**EXPLAIN of the SELECT Stat**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          stats   range   DateLastView    DateLastView    4   NULL    25242   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

That result set is looped and inserted into the compiled table.  Unfortunately I don't have support for batched inserts with this (I tried) so I have to loop through these one at a time instead of sending a batch of 100 or 500 to the server at a time.  This is inserted into the master DB.

```
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO stats_daily (VID, ViewCount, YearMonthDay, DateModified) VALUES ({$result->VID}, {$result->ViewCount}, '{$result->YearMonthDay}', {$today} );

    DoQuery($query);
}
```

Comment: What if any errors are you seeing from the Master while it appaers to stop during your processing on the Slave.

Comment: I think you also should send parts of your cronjob script what querys you run and also run EXPLAIN on those querys and post the results here with good info on what query generated what explain.

Comment: Check your mysql tmp dir (if your on linux this could be /tmp to see if there are MYD or MYI files there if you run the cronjob make please you use ll and enter a couple off times). If they are that's not good because disk based temporary tables are created then what will kill performance

Comment: I updated the post with the EXPLAIN and the script.  It's not really that fancy of a script.  Simple fetch data for a day, then compile it and throw it into the compiled table.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY is the culprit. Apparently MySQL decides to use a temporary table in this case (perhaps because the table has exceeded some limit) which is very inefficient.

I ran into similar problems, but no clear solution. You could consider splitting your `stats` table into two tables, a 'daily' and a 'history' table. Run your query on the 'daily' table which only contains entries from the latest 24 hours or whatever your interval is, then clean up the table. 
To get the info into your permanent 'history' table, either write your stats into both tables from code, or copy them over from daily into history before cleanup.